# WPF Problemas al utilizar IRegionManager

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Utilizo este método para llamar a una vista :

```
IRegionManager regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();

//Esta es la interfaz que implementara el CodeBehind de la vista.

IListaBeneficiosPopupView busquedaBeneficioPopup = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IListaBeneficiosPopupView>();

regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.FlyoutRegion].Add(busquedaBeneficioPopup, "busquedaBeneficioPopup"); 

regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.FlyoutRegion].Activate(busquedaBeneficioPopup);
```

Mi objetivo es que las vistas carguen de la siguiente forma y en el siguiente orden :

> 1. Vista A -> 2. Vista B ->3. Vista C

pero el resultado actual es que cuando cargo la vista `C`, esta se abre detrás de la vista `B`, cuando debería mostrarse encima.

¿Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: En ese código no veo cuando llamas a las otras dos vistas, por lo que es complicado seguir el hilo y encontrar el problema. ¿Has mirado en tu Bootstrapper el InitializationMode? Igual lo tienes WhenAvailable y se cargan en cuanto se puede.